# CSS Hover behind a margin

Tags: html, css, background, hover

I have a content area in the middle of the page, which I am centering with `margin: 0 auto;`
Now I want to have a background effect on the page with several small cubes, that, when hovered change with some effects.

The hover effects work fine under or over the content area, but the problem is that the margin, which centers the content seems to disturb the recognition of the hovering, because when hovered over the cubes behind the margin of the content area, the hover selector doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Here a code example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/dl3ojm0g

Comment: can you show your codes or put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: have you tried to play with the `z-index` of your content area?

Comment: Any codes or demonstration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small changes in the CSS and it works well.

```
    #content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position:relative;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 700px;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 2px solid darkgray;
        color: darkgray;
        z-index:2;
    }
    #cubeHolder {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index:1;
}
```

Just needed to position `#content` to relative and gave it a higher z-index comparing to `#cubeHolder`

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/nwrFa/6/

Comment: Thanks, thats even better, when resizing the window!

Answer (score 1):

Position your content-container absolute. Then left: 50% and margin-left: -700px/2

```
#content {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -350px;
width: 700px;
height: 300px;
padding: 20px;
background-color: white;
border: 2px solid darkgray;
color: darkgray; }
```

Comment: This is a good workaround but it's not the perfect solution for the question. Check my answer.